# How can I apply port forwarding to an Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, containers

I've been experimenting with a containerised app that listens for and processes TCP traffic on a specified port.

To make this work on my own physical machine that was acting as the host I had to setup port forwarding from it to the container.

I've since deployed the dockerized app to an Azure Container Instance, which runs as expected and starts listening on own IP address and the specified port **BUT** I can't find a way to setup port forwarding so that traffic sent to the public IP address assigned to the container group can get to the app, is this possible?

This [article on container groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups) seems to suggest it is but doesn't seem to say how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer from Microsoft Support (posting here in case anyone has the same question)

Unfortunately Port forwarding is not supported in ACI yet and it’s in roadmap.

UPDATE

It looks like this answer from support is wrong. Ports specified when creating the container group are automatically published so containers with exposed ports can receive traffic from the outside, the issue I was having was with a problem with my code.

Comment: Did they say whether there are other services that will provide the port forwarding? VPN? Load balancers? I'm pretty unfamiliar with Azure.